# Adding to an array using a no arg constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I seem to be stuck on how to add to an array by using a no-arg constructor. What is it that I am missing here?

```
public class Book {
private String title;
private String author;
private int pages;
private double price;
public static int numBooks = 0;


public Book(String title, String author, int pages, double price) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.price = price;
    numBooks++;
}
public Book() {
    super();
    numBooks++;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public int getPages() {
    return pages;
}

public void setPages(int pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "book [title=" + title + ", author=" + author + ", pages=" + pages + ", price=" + price + "]";
}

public static int getNumBooks(){ 
    return numBooks;
}
```

This is where I am having a lot of trouble. I have my in main and below it I have my no arg constructor that I can't figure out how to add the array in main. Any advice or pointers in the right direction would great.

}

```
public class TestBook {
private String title;
private String author;
private int pages;
private double price;

public TestBook(String title, String author, int pages, double price){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.price = price;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Book[] bookArray = new Book[6]; //This is the array that I am trying to add the last two books too 

    Book bookArray0 = new Book("Java Proramming", "Liang", 1320, 145.00);
    Book bookArray1 = new Book("Horton Hears a Who", "Dr. Seuss", 72, 19.99);
    Book bookArray2 = new Book("The Hobbit", "Tolkien", 320, 9.25);
    Book bookArray3 = new Book("Born a Crime", "Noah", 304, 17.33);
    Book bookArray4 = new Book();
    Book bookArray5 = new Book();

    bookArray[0] = bookArray0;
    bookArray[1] = bookArray1;
    bookArray[2] = bookArray2;
    bookArray[3] = bookArray3;
    bookArray[4] = bookArray4;
    bookArray[5] = bookArray5;


    for(Book d : bookArray)
        System.out.println(d);


}

public TestBook() { //This is the no-arg that I am trying to use to add to the array above.
    Book[] bookArray = new Book[6];
    Book bookArray4 = new Book("The Town", "Chuck Hogan", 477, 14.99);
    Book bookArray5 = new Book("The Pretender ", "Sombody", 400, 24.99);
    bookArray[4] = bookArray4;
    bookArray[5] = bookArray5;

    for(Book b : bookArray)
        System.out.println(b);

    }

public void finishArray(){
Book lastBook = new Book();
lastBook.setTitle(title);
lastBook.setAuthor(author);
lastBook.setPages(pages);
lastBook.setPrice(price);

}
```

}

Comment: BTW, there's no need to call `super`. It's done implicitly.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I cannot seem to be able add the last two books in to the array. The array just prints null instead of the two books that I am trying to add.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Li I have taken out calling super

Answer (score 0):

You're getting null because you're not setting data to those objects. That is what the setTitle and setAuthor are for. So something like

```
  bookArray4.setTitle("The Town");
  bookArray4.setAuthor("Somebody");
```

When you used a constructor that passed the information these things were set in it. But with the constructor with no arguments no data is passed to it. So you use your "Setter" Methods to set the data

Answer (score 0):

As *Sean Reaves* pointed out, you need to use your setters for the books created with the default constructor.

**The Book**

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int pages;
    private double price;
    private static int numBooks = 0;

    public Book(String title, String author, int pages, double price) {
        this();
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Book() {
        numBooks++;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(int pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "book [title=" + this.title + ", author=" + this.author + ", pages=" + this.pages + ", price=" + this.price + "]";
    }

    public static int getNumBooks() {
        return numBooks;
    }
}
```

I made some minor changes to your code, just to clean things up a bit.

**Main**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // All books
        Book[] books = new Book[] { 
            new Book("Java Proramming", "Liang", 1320, 145.00),
            new Book("Horton Hears a Who", "Dr. Seuss", 72, 19.99), 
            new Book("The Hobbit", "Tolkien", 320, 9.25),
            new Book("Born a Crime", "Noah", 304, 17.33), 
            new Book(), 
            new Book() 
        };

        // Use setters to avoid null values
        books[5].setAuthor("Not Null Author");
        books[5].setTitle("Not Null Title");

        // Print
        Arrays.asList(books).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

You could call your setters for the `price` and `pages` attributes as well.

**Output**

```
book [title=Java Proramming, author=Liang, pages=1320, price=145.0]
book [title=Horton Hears a Who, author=Dr. Seuss, pages=72, price=19.99]
book [title=The Hobbit, author=Tolkien, pages=320, price=9.25]
book [title=Born a Crime, author=Noah, pages=304, price=17.33]
book [title=null, author=null, pages=0, price=0.0]
book [title=Not Null Title, author=Not Null Author, pages=0, price=0.0]
```